# Linear sum of foreign key count django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a profile class in my model like follow:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    first_name = ....
    ....
```

I two other classes that has foreign key to profile model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    ....

class B(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

Now I want to filter active users. I want something like follows. But I don't know how to do it in django!

```
UserProfile.objects.filter((2*count(A) + count(B))__gte=10).all()
```

Comment: I want to select users with this expression having value bigger than 10

Comment: I think you are not using Django user default model in User Profile model. So can you add UserProfile Model full structure here?

Comment: My question is not related to authentication user. You can substitute "UserProfile" with any other class, e.g. "C"

Comment: But 2*count(A) + count(B)) there should be a field not any logic. So we need to field name there that will calculate and filter data from UserProfile.  and you want __gte=10 that means field should be integer type that can match this condition not any logic

Comment: Sorry sir I don't get you.
2*count(A) + count(B) this expression is an integer!

Comment: I want to calculate sum of A model objects that have a foreign key to UserProfile raised by a factor of 2 + B model objects that have also a foreign key to that UserProfile

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR and As you see this is an integer ! What do you mean by logic?

Comment: Do you have any idea what are you trying in filter queryset ?  You want filter active users but "(2*count(A) + count(B))__gte=10" this logic doesn't have any mean with filter. (2*count(A) + count(B)) this should be simple field name of Model not any expressions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146788/discussion-between-neeraj-kumar-and-mohammad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `annotate` on the queryset first to run the calculation, then you can filter by it.

```
from django.db.models import Count

UserProfile.objects.annotate(
    score=2*Count('a') + Count('b')
).filter(score__gte=10)
```

Comment: Thanks @Brobin for answer